# Multithreaded comet server library

Tags: asynchronous, comet, epoll

I'm looking for multithreaded comet server library - what I need is async io (using epoll) working on a threadpool (4-8 threads). Tornado would be ideal if it was multithreaded.

Why multithreaded? I need to process and serve data which could come from every connected user - it could be synchronised between tornado instances using database but even nosql would be too big slowdown - almost every request would end up with database write/update - which even by using async drivers isn't a good idea. I can store everything in local volataile memory so it can be very fast - but must be run on single process to avoid inter-process communication. I don't need to scale - single box is enough - but it MUST be fast. Some data will be stored in MongoDB - but number of mongo queries will be like 5% of normal requests.

And important thing - semaphores (and other higher level approaches) are not rocket science for me so I'm not afraid of synchronisation.

Requirements:

- async io
- non-blocking
- thousands of concurrent connections
- FAST
- basic HTTP features (GET, POST, cookies)
- ability to process request asynchronously (do something, async call with callback (ex. database query), process callback, return data)
- thread pool
- C++/Java/Python
- simple and lightweight

It would be nice to have async mongo driver too

I've looked into Boost ASIO and it seems to be capable of doing what I need - but I want to focus on application - not writing http request processing.

I've read about [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) (seems ideal but is single threaded), [Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org/) (not sure if it can process request asynchronously and return data after async call), [BOOST ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/asio/) (very nice, but too low-level)

Answer (score 1):

Well, after more digging I decided to change technology... I decided to create my own protocol on top of TCP and [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty)